# How to map a csv line to a collection of keyword dictionaries?

Tags: parsing, csv, clojure, mapping

Let's assume I have the following csv:

```
DATE;DESC;IN;OUT
11/04/13;Buy new shoes;;90
16/04/13;Wage;5000;
17/04/13;Donate money;;200
;;;
30/04/13;Buy new shoes again;;80
```

I basically want to parse this csv file, filter out empty lines and later on, perform some calculations on it. I do not want to use any pre-made csv libraries whatsoever because I am relatively new to clojure and want to learn it the hard way.

Here is what I did so far:

```
(ns calc
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]
            [clojure.string :as str]))

(defn filter-empty-lines [coll]
  (filter #(not (.startsWith % ";;;")) coll))

(defn parse-lines [coll]
  (let [columns [:date :desc :out :in]]
     headers (map name columns)
     --> STUCK

(defn calculate-costs [f]
  (->> (io/reader f)
    line-seq
    filter-empty-lines    
    parse-lines))

(calculate-costs "/var/tmp/in_out.csv")
```

Basically the filtering of the empty lines already works but I am kinda stuck with the mapping of the parsed csv lines.

My idea was to simply split the lines by ; and use **zipmap to create a dictonary with keywords** and the csv values for each line and add it to a collection.

I did not get the parse-lines function to work and would be happy if somebody could help out. I'd also appreciate any clojure related hints / ideas of improvement.

Thx in advance

**UPDATE**

---

Thanks to the answer from bsvingen, I ended up with the following:

```
(defn parse-lines [coll]
  (map #(let [[date desc out in] (clojure.string/split % #";")]
    {:date date :desc desc :out out :in in}) coll))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this?

```
(let [[date desc out in] (clojure.string/split "17/04/13;Donate money;;200" #";")]
  {:date date :desc desc :out out :in in})
```

(Read about [destructuring](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20(Destructuring)).)

The complete function can then look like this:

```
(defn make-map [csv-line]
  (let [[date desc out in] (clojure.string/split csv-line #";")]
    {:date date :desc desc :out out :in in}))

(defn parse-lines [coll]
  (map make-map coll))
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Could you please have a look on the solution I posted on my modified question? If you agree on it, I'll give you the right answer.

Comment: Yes, this looks good, though I would move `coll` to the next line to make it easier to read (so that the two arguments to `map` are lined up).

Comment: Maybe even take the first one out as a separate, named function.

Comment: I added a complete suggestion to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Following is a solution where you can use the first line (headers) of the file to compute the keywords:

```
(defn headers [line]
  (map keyword (str/split line #";")))
```

Then to parse one line and return a map with headers

```
(defn parse-line [headers line]
  (zipmap headers (str/split line #";")))
```

Parsing the all file gives:

```
(defn parse-lines [coll]
  (let [head (headers (first coll))]
    (map (partial parse-line head) (rest coll))))
```

Now you have kind of a spreadsheet as a map, you can sum on a given column:

```
(defn calculate [sheet column-key]
  (->> sheet
       (map column-key)
       (filter (complement nil?))
       (map #(Integer/parseInt %))
       (reduce +)))
```

And computing cost:

```
(with-open [file (io/reader "./calc.csv")]
  (let [sheet (->> file
                   line-seq
                   filter-empty-lines
                   parse-lines)]
    (calculate sheet :OUT)))
```

Comment: Now that you have a solution and more of an idea, I would recommend having a look at clojure.data.csv Once of the really useful aspects of Clojure is that you can easily view the source code. Now that you have an idea of how it can be done, the source code will mean more and this will really help with getting comfortable with Clojure idioms and techniques

Comment: Thx @TimX. My intention was to start with the core basics from scratch and later on replace my code by something stable and well-tested as it evolves. This few lines of clojure code already gave me some valuable insights and better understanding how to tackle problems in clojure. Actually it looks like a nice DSL at the end :)